# Illegal Instruction starting Apache -> PEM_read_bio_X509

Tags: apache, ubuntu, openssl

I'm working on Ubuntu 13.10 64bits and I built Apache 2.2.17 and openSSL 0.9.8b from source with this configuration :

- openssl : ./config prefix=/repository no-asm
- apache : ./configure \
  --prefix=/opt/httpd \
  --with-included-apr \
  --enable-ssl \
  --with-ssl=/opt/openssl-1.0.1e \
  --enable-ssl-staticlib-deps \
  --enable-mods-static=ssl (stactic build !)

When I try to start my apache without SSL it works but when I try to start with ssl (Include httpd-ssl.conf in httpd.conf) I got this error :
**Illegal Instruction (core dumped)**

I localized this error in httpd-ssl.conf at the line **SSLCertificateFile file**.
Then I try to run it with GDB and this is what I got :

> Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
>   0x00000000004e7b20 in PEM_read_bio_X509 () 
>   (gdb) where
>
> 0  0x00000000004e7b20 in PEM_read_bio_X509 ()
>
> 1  0x0000000000488159 in SSL_read_X509 (
>       filename=filename@entry=0x7fffffffc440 "/home/dinou/httpd_build/serveur.cert", x509=x509@entry=0x0,
>   cb=cb@entry=0x0) at ssl_util_ssl.c:86
>
> 2  0x0000000000480c9d in ssl_pphrase_Handle (s=s@entry=0x85af78, 
>       p=p@entry=0x88c368) at ssl_engine_pphrase.c:206
>
> 3  0x000000000047ad20 in ssl_init_Module (p=0x846138, plog=, 
>       ptemp=0x88c368, base_server=0x85af78) at ssl_engine_init.c:290
>
> 4  0x0000000000461569 in ap_run_post_config (pconf=0x846138, plog=0x88a358, 
>       ptemp=0x88c368, s=0x85af78) at config.c:91
>
> 5  0x000000000044e29b in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe6e8) at main.c:679

I verified that my certificate was PEM format and that's okay.

Any Ideas ? 
Thanks

EDIT : Here's the script to build & install all

```
#!/bin/bash
#OPENSSL_VERSION="0.9.8b"
#HTTPD_VERSION="2.2.17"
check_errs()
{
  if [ "${1}" -ne "0" ]; then
    echo "ERROR # ${1} : ${2}" 1>&2; 
    exit ${1}
  fi
}

WORKDIR=`mktemp -d`
check_errs $? "temp dir creation"
echo "WORKDIR=$WORKDIR"

cd $WORKDIR
wget http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-$OPENSSL_VERSION.tar.gz
check_errs $? "wget openssl $OPENSSL_VERSION ;; in $WORKDIR"
tar zxf openssl-$OPENSSL_VERSION.tar.gz
check_errs $? "untar openssl $OPENSSL_VERSION ;; in $WORKDIR"
cd openssl-$OPENSSL_VERSION
check_errs $? "cd openssl $OPENSSL_VERSION ;; in $WORKDIR"
./config \
    --prefix=$WORKDIR/ssl \
    --openssldir=$WORKDIR/ssl \
    no-asm
check_errs $? "config openssl $OPENSSL_VERSION ;; in $WORKDIR"
make
check_errs $? "make openssl $OPENSSL_VERSION ;; in $WORKDIR"
make install
check_errs $? "make install openssl $OPENSSL_VERSION ;; in $WORKDIR"

cd $WORKDIR
wget http://mir2.ovh.net/ftp.apache.org/dist//httpd/httpd-$HTTPD_VERSION.tar.gz
check_errs $? "wget httpd-$HTTPD_VERSION ;; in $WORKDIR"
tar zxf httpd-$HTTPD_VERSION.tar.gz
check_errs $? "untar httpd-$HTTPD_VERSION ;; in $WORKDIR"
cd httpd-$HTTPD_VERSION
check_errs $? "cd httpd-$HTTPD_VERSION ;; in $WORKDIR"
./configure \
    --prefix=$WORKDIR/apache \
    --with-included-apr \
    --enable-ssl \
    --with-ssl=$WORKDIR/ssl \
    --enable-ssl-staticlib-deps \
    --enable-mods-static=ssl
check_errs $? "configure httpd-$HTTPD_VERSION ;; in $WORKDIR"
make
check_errs $? "make httpd-$HTTPD_VERSION ;; in $WORKDIR"
make install 
check_errs $? "make install httpd-$HTTPD_VERSION ;; in $WORKDIR"

cd $WORKDIR/apache/conf
check_errs $? "cd apache ;; in $WORKDIR"
$WORKDIR/ssl/bin/openssl req -x509 -out server.crt -keyout server.key -days 900 -newkey rsa:1024 -subj '/CN=localhost' -nodes
check_errs $? "key generation ;; in $WORKDIR"
echo "SSLEngine On"                          >>httpd.conf
echo "SSLCertificateFile    conf/server.crt" >>httpd.conf
echo "SSLCertificateKeyFile conf/server.key" >>httpd.conf
sed -i 's/Listen \*:80/Listen *:8443/' ports.conf
check_errs $? "sed ;; in $WORKDIR"
```

Comment: Well your scripts file location and the debug output seem to differ. One has `/home/dinou/httpd_build/serveur.cert` and the config file points to `conf/server.crt`.

I don't know how you checked the file, but if you do `openssl x509 -noout -text -in <filename here>` and this shows something useful I guess you can assume the file is ok.